# (Android) Crash a app by android.content.ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, crashlytics

I got a crashlytics report about `ActivityNotFoundException` error:

```
"android.content.ActivityNotFoundException - No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details/... }"
```

I've found this error on minor models such as Google Jump 2 and Google XCover 5.
I'd like to know the reason.

Comment: The reason is in error message but it is really irrelevant. Solution is to always wrap startActivity() in try/catch block ans deal with it

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  but 
I'd like to know why It can't move to Google Market due to a certain condition in more detail. I guess this could happen when Google Market is not updated or has been deleted or not stopped. I would like to know if this problem can occur on a specific device.

Comment: I suppose it is always possible someone has rooted their phone and uninstalled Google Play Store after downloading your app. Or maybe if the Google Play Store app is in the middle of an update while you try to open it, this could happen.

Comment: You should not bother the root cause as it is outside of your control and you will not be able to fix that, no matter what it is. The only lesson for you to learn now is  `startActivity()` should be wrapped in `try/catch` block to prevent your app from crashing. esp. when calling external activities. Once you got that corrected in your app, you are done.